# asp.net, Gridview RowEditing event only works on first row

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im working on asp.net with c#.
I have a gridview with templatefield columns, data comes from an sql database. I have linkbutton on the item template, the linkbutton calls the Rowediting event to enable the editing. This works fine on the first row. But when I click on any of the other rows nothing happens, the event never gets fires.

How can I solve this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are data-binding the grid in the Page_Load event.  If this is the case, the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx&ei=E3hXUNCHAbOByQHbu4DoCg&usg=AFQjCNH7k8oXjBvm9VNxhszmprCq5wkVvw) is getting in your way.  (Be sure to read the article in the link provided. Every .NET developer needs to know about the Page_Lifecycle.  It explains a lot of behavior thaqt would otherwise cause confusion, such as this behavior.)

The Page_Load event happens on every postback - every button click, or any event that triggers the postback.

If this is the case, there are two possible options:

1. Move your data binding code to Page_Init
2. Put your data-binding in Page_Load inside an `if(!Page.IsPostback)` block.

In essence, the problem is that your page is data-binding on the first load.
Then the editing event is triggered by some client action, which triggers a postback. In this postback, Page_Load fires first, which re-binds the GridView, erasing all of the data that was associated with it on the previous load.  So when the RowEditing event fires (control events always happen AFTER Page_Load) there's nothing for it to do. All references to the data as it existed before postback are gone.

If you move your binding code too Page_Init, you can get around this because the page will be bound, and then all of the Viewstate will be re-applied to it, restoring the data that was lost in the postback in the scenario above.

Comment: It was the Gridview font size, it seems that the size was not so good for clicking, I just put it in a larger size and now is good. Thanks.

Comment: @pyram -  Oh.. If my answer wasn't the right one, I'd feel better if you deleted the question rather than accepting an incorrect answer. It's better (less misleading) for future visitors.  I'm more worried about being helpful than I am about the points.  I don't know if you have enough rep to delete, but if not, I can always flag it and ask a moderator to delete it for you.  Just let me know.